# Spring retrieving one user by id

Tags: spring

I currently have on a page a list of users that I retrieved from the database. Along with the users is the associated child objects, but what I would like to do is on that same page instead of a list of all users, it would just one user that is currently logged in to the application. So they are restricted from viewing all of the user details and should just be able to view their own specific details and child objects.

DAO - the method for getting all users

```
public List<Module> getSetterModules(Integer userId){

      Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

      Query query = session.createQuery("FROM UserEntity as u WHERE 
              u.userId="+userId);

      UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity) query.uniqueResult();

      return  new ArrayList<Module>(userEntity.getsModule());
```

The dto for retrieving a list of users and the associated objects which I would like to retrieve only the one user (that is authenticated) by their id and list all of the objects linked to them. I'm attempting to implementing it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getRecords(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, ModelMap 

        model) {

    //Retrieve one user
     UserEntity user = userService.getUserByID(userId);
     UserEntityDTO userDTO = new UserEntityDTO();


     UserEntityDTO dto = new UserEntityDTO();
     dto.setUserId(user.getUserId());
     dto.setsModule(moduleService.getSetterModules(user.getUserId()));
     dto.setcModule(moduleService.getCheckerModules(user.getUserId()));

     userDTO.add(dto);
     }
     model.addAttribute("user", userDTO); 

      return "/main";}
```

I would like some insight how to proceed from here or is there a simpler way of getting the user.

New DAO

```
@Transactional
public UserEntity getUserByID(Integer userId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity) session.get(UserEntity.class, userId);
    userEntity.getsModule();

            return userEntity;}
```

Controller

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/main/user/testing", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRecords(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, ModelMap 

        model) {
     UserEntity userEntity = userService.getUserByID(userId);

     model.addAttribute("user", userEntity);

     return "/main/user/testing";
 }
```

Error

```
     HTTP Status 400 - Required Integer parameter 'userId' is not present
```

Edit 2: The above implementation url was returning the error above so I tried to hardcode the id into the url:

```
   <c:url value="/main/user/testing/?userId=2" var="url"/><a href="<c:out 

   value='${url}'/>">test</a>
```

And changed the controller to:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/main/user/testing{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRecords(@RequestParam("userId") Integer userId, ModelMap 

        model) {
     UserEntity userEntity = userService.getUserByID(userId);

     model.addAttribute("user", userEntity);

     return "/main/user/testing";
 }
```

But the error is now:

```
    javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:274)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:238)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main.user.testing_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(testing_jsp.java:181)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main.user.testing_jsp._jspService(testing_jsp.java:125)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

This is the jsp I want to get:

```
   <table>
        <tr>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Module Code</th>
                    <th>Module Name</th>
              </tr>


       <c:forEach items="${setter}" var="obj" >
        <c:forEach items="${obj.sModule}" var="module" >


            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${obj.userId}" escapeXml="true" /></td>


                <td><c:out value="${module.moduleCode}" escapeXml="true" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${module.moduleName}" escapeXml="true" /></td>



            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

I really would like to know how I get the user and the associated modules and without having to hard code the userId into the url. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `get` method on `Session` ([Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29))

```
session.get(UserEntity.class, userId);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have implemented it and written a cocntroller for it with a userId parameter, but its returning the error -  Required Integer parameter 'userId' is not present. I have updated the first post with it.

Comment: Post the form or ajax that submits the request

Comment: I have edited the first post. I made some alterations to my url request and controller which now returns a stack trace error. I would appreciate a look at it.